# Slow website loss times on Google.com and apple.com

Tags: ios, cellular-data, web-browser

I've noticed that recently when I try to use Google products or (more specifically) try to access apple.com, there are slow 30-60 second wait times or no load whatsoever. This applies to all web browsers that I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). I have no VPN connections or device profiles. This also only occurs when I'm using cellular data.

iPhone 8 Plus
iOS 11.4.1
Carrier: Verizon Wireless 32.0
Available space: 20 GB/64 GB

Comment: If it’s fast on WiFi you can be sure you’ll want to work with your carrier or are you looking for software recommendations to get concrete data so you can prove to the carrier it’s their problem.

Comment: when was it last time you did an Update ?

Comment: @bmike Software hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

A similar error may be due to the low speed of the Internet. Check this information. The second way, I recommend checking and resetting errors on your iPhone.